# Cargar una Tabla en Python con PysimpleGUI

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Tengo la siguiente duda:

Quiero hacer un programa en python que realice una búsqueda en una hoja de excel. Ejemplo: Si le pongo "Independencia", que busque en una hoja de excel cuantos nombres coinciden con la palabra misma. La hoja de excel cuenta con 3 columnas (Numero, Nombre, Ubicación)

El problema es que al hacer el filtro o la búsqueda:

```
df_columns = (excel_file_df[['Numero', 'Nombre', 'Ubicacion']])
df_content = excel_file_df.loc[df_columns['Nombre'].str.contains(values['-INPUT-'])
```

No se como cargar el resultado a una tabla con PySimpleGUI.
Como nota: Utilicé pandas para entrar al archivo de excel y poder leerlo.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Ya revisaste en qué formato queda la búsqueda? Pues, si lo imprimes en pantalla o algo, va a ser más fácil manipularlo...

Comment: Muchas Gracias por el apoyo, ya quedo solucionado, Que Tengan Buena Tarde

Comment: Pues, si deseas, podrías compartir la solución abajo en el campo de Respuesta. Puedes recibir votos positivos y puedes marcarla tú mismx como aceptada.

Comment: ah ok, ahorita lo pongo, no se me habia ocurrido

Answer (score 1):

les paso como quedo el codigo completo, donde hago una busqueda desde un archivo de excel y el resultado lo muestro en una tabla, todo usando PySimpleGUI y Pandas . . .

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd

archivo_df = pd.read_excel("Ruta\\'Base de datos'")

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Ingrese la busqueda')],
    [sg.Input(key='input_buscar'), sg.Button('Buscar')],
    [sg.Table(values=[], headings=archivo_df.columns.tolist(), key = '-TABLA-', num_rows = 10, expand_x=True, justification = 'center')]

    ]

window = sg.Window('Laminas', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    
    if event == 'Buscar':
        busqueda = values['input_buscar']
        resultados = archivo_df[archivo_df['Nombre'].str.contains(busqueda, na = False)]

        window['-TABLA-'].update(values=resultados.values.tolist())
        window['-TABLA-'].expand(expand_x=True, expand_y=False, expand_row=True)

window.close()
```